# Submit New App Version in New iTunes Connect after Developer Rejection

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I removed my build from the submission queue in the new iTunes Connect. Now when I submit new builds to the app store they show up under 'Prerelease' but not under 'Versions'. So now in my App Info it just says "1.0 Ready for Sale   1.0.25 Developer Rejected".

Under "Versions" I only see 1.0 and 1.0.25. Under "Prerelease" I see lots of new versions, going up to 1.0.31.

I am doing something wrong?

There is no option to create a new version like there used to be. I also didn't get an email after the upload from Xcode 6.0.1. The result of the Xcode uploads were all successful and gave me a thank you message.

Comment: You have to change 1.0.25 from Developer Rejected to Ready for Upload.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

- Go to the developer rejected version
- Where is says 'Build', hover over the build version number. A red dot appears!
- Click on the red dot next to 'build' - this seems to remove the build from the version
- Select a new build Submit for Review

Comment: In addition to the great instructions above, you can also edit the revision number in the "Version" box (after doing the above).   That was my problem, I also wanted to change the revision to rev 2.00 and couldn't figure that out.

Comment: Amazing!  I thought I was going nuts!  Is there a way we can tell Apple to reject Itunes connect!

Comment: Perfect answer.. Wasted one day in finding answer on google. Tomorrow onwards appstore having holiday break for next 8-10 days. Saved my time. Thanks

Comment: @LevinsonTechnologies Exactly my problem! It's a little box to update the version number

Comment: Having to hover over something to wait for a red dot to appear is an example of bad UI design. How intuitive is that? I have not seen this mentioned in Apple docs anywhere, and Apple support people haven't mentioned it to me either.  Please take note Apple

Comment: Do I need to submit ipa again for updated itunes connected version ? I mean if I added 3.11.2 and it is in status as "Prepare for Submission" and I have uploaded build for 3.11.2 it is working and it is in Test flight--- now at some later point my team decides lets have 3.12 without 3.11.2. How this should be handled ?

Comment: This did not work for me. I hovered over build number but no red dot appeared

Answer (score 6):

Adding the pictures to clarify. 
You have to replace the rejected build, with an updated build.

This is key: **You must replace the build in the rejected iOS version.**

Select the app version from the sidebar select the iOS version that was rejected.

[image: You must replace the build for the rejected iOS version.]

Scroll down to the build section.
[image: Hover over the build link for the red dot.]

Remove the rejected build: **Hover your mouse over the build. You should see a red circle appear.** (The circle is how you remove the build from the iOS version that was rejected).

In the build section, select a new build. (If you haven’t uploaded a new build you will need to do that first.)

Now you will be able submit the app for review.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

The red-dot would look like this, you need to move your mouse hover the version no!

Answer (score 2):

Remove the build from the section, just hover the mouse over the build number (blue link, do not click, just hover), an icon will apear, click on it, and remove the build.

[image]

just bellow that, there is a section that you can change the version number, change it and save.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to the 1.0 version which is ready for Sale and add a new version to match your release.  Then you need to upload your binary with the same version.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Where do I do that? I don't see the option.

Answer (score 0):

```
> Go to the developer rejected version and then below build section,
> hover the build version then cancel the build with a red icon.
> then select new build from test flight.
> then just press submit for review, your app will be under review.
> also in version textfield, you can change version number.
```

it works for me.