# iTunes Connect warning: "Your binary doesn’t support iPad"

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, cordova, app-store-connect

I just uploaded a new binary to iTunes Connect and added it to a new version of an iOS app.

After adding the binary and saving changes, iTunes Connect displays the warning message:

"Your binary doesn’t support iPad. The screenshots or app video preview for iPad won’t be shown on the App Store."

[image]

The Xcode project was generated using the Cordova 3 CLI; the uploaded binary is the first Cordova 3 version since the app was migrated from Cordova 2.

The app has been tested on iPad and it works fine.

Xcode project setting for devices is "Universal" (TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY = "1,2" in project.pbxproj):

[image]

Xcode architecture settings are the defaults, so they are not explicitly specified in project.pbxproj:

[image]

I've Googled this warning message and found no useful information, so hoping someone here has come across this before and can offer some advice.

Comment: Have you found anything out on this?  I also just uploaded an app that runs full capabilities on iPad, and set to Universal and got the same message.

Comment: I haven't found anything so far (note the lack of answers). I think I will have to ask Apple tech support. I'll post the response they give me.

Comment: Thanks. I am betting it is just a glitch and will still be put in iPad AppStore.

Comment: Any news on this. I have submitted a bug report to apple.

Comment: I've submitted a Tech Support ticket to Apple, but not heard anything yet

Comment: Did your app approved with iphone/ipad support? or you need to do anything? I have same issue and I'm confused @DaveAlden

Comment: @Scorpian Alive: Ignore the warning message - my app was approved anyway

Comment: I wonder, did you ever submit a build to iTunes connect that was iPhone only? I had done for a while, then made it Universal, and just got this warning upon submission.

Comment: I think the previous version was iPhone-only (I've taken this app over from another developer, so it has quite a long history before I got my hands on it) - you may be onto something there. If that's the cause, at least (from my experience) it doesn't actually cause any issues when switching to Universal and submitted for review.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

My app was reviewed and approved for release, despite this warning message, so I can only assume it's an issue with iTunes Connect.

It now appears in the App Store with "This app is designed for both iPhone and iPad" and the iPad screenshots are shown.

My advice to others is to ignore it and submit your app for review.

Comment: Thanks for following up and sharing your success - hoping I have the same luck.

Comment: We got tripped up by submitting an old build for a previous version. With nothing in review, there is an option to add a version under the "Versions" tab (+ symbol). That will allow you to pick your latest binary for review. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26371047/submit-new-app-version-in-new-itunes-connect-after-developer-rejection