# Itunes connect doesn't detect iPad binary

Tags: ios, ipad, app-store-connect

I uploaded an update to an app I have. The update adds universal support to run full capability on iPad. After adding iPad screenshots, I got error message

"Your binary doesn’t support iPad. The screenshots or app video preview for iPad won’t be shown on the App Store."

In the general tab in Xcode I have it set to Universal app and not iphone. Under image assets I have the required iPad icons and launch screen stuff for iPad sizes.

Is this just an iTunes connect glitch or did I mess something up?  If it goes through and adds to iPad appstor that is fine but if I wait 10 days for an update only to not have it work on iPad i would be pretty ticked.

Comment: How it could be "Universal app" and "not iphone"? I think, it could be just: iPad, iPhone or universal.

Comment: It is universal and not ONLY iphone on settings. Thought that was clear

Comment: Maybe you could upload your binary first from archive menu and than trying to add screenshots before submission?

Comment: This seems to be the same problem as http://stackoverflow.com/q/28503020/1449607